# sed regex not matching

Tags: text, sed, replace

I have more than one instance of a string per line and I only need to prepend one of them I marked the other ones I dont want to change to Sports CommunincationP I am using

```
sed  -i.bak 's/Sports Communication[^P]/College of Architecture\, Arts and Humanities\/Sports Communication/' out.csv
```

to try to prepend the unaltered string below is the csv content I am interested in

```
2.5,"Sports Communication,","The Campus
```

I am probably missing something simple. I tried /g at end to see if I had more than one match I missed altering. I also took away the [^P] make sure no typos and it matches

Comment: It is not clear to me what your input and expected output are.

Comment: i need to replace any instances of Sports Communication or SportsCommunication, with College of Architecture\, Arts and Humanities/Sports Communication but not Sports CommunicationP

Comment: @benjamin W. I found a way, I used sed  -i.bak 's/[0-9\,\"]Sports Communication/\,\"College of Architecture\/ Arts and Humanities\/Sports Communication/' out.csv to look for that pattern as a delimiter thanks again. My first solution was that there was only a single count on that one line so I was matching Sports CommunicationP thanks!!!

Comment: Would you like to create an answer yourself? I think Q/A pairs are better than Q/comment pairs.

Comment: I hesitate to put my solution as an answer since it only works for my very specific input can I delete the question?

Comment: You can delete the question. But in my opinioin it is also OK to give the answer which solved your particular problem for particularily you. And then accept it. Upvoting will probably not happen... ;-) By the way, if you answer to a comment like mine, use @brad syntax. Then we get a special notification and can more promptly answer. I do not actually need to do that, because you as the OP will always be notified about changes/comments to your question.